# PHP check if string is in array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array that looks like this:

`{"permissions":["1","2"]}`

I'm trying to check if a given string is in the permissions array with the following function

```
function hasPermission($permission) {
            return in_array($permission, array_column($this->permissions, 'permissions'));
}
```

When calling the function giving it the string "1" it return false even though 1 is in the permissions array

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

EDIT

Here is a var Dump of the converted array

```
array(1) { 
    ["permissions"]=> 
array(2) {[0]=> string(1) "1" 
          [1]=> string(1) "2" 
        } 
}
```

Comment: Did you convert the JSON String to a PHP Object/Array before running this code

Comment: If you did it woild be useful to see a `var_dump()` of the Object/Array

Comment: I converted the array with json_deocde()
Here is a var Dump of the converted array
array(1) { ["permissions"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" } }

Comment: Better to edit you question with additional info, nobody can read code in a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this...

```
<?php
$json = '{"permissions":["1","2"]}';
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
print_r($arr);
echo in_array(1,$arr['permissions']); // returns 1 if exists
?>
```

So your function must be like this....

```
function hasPermission($permission) {
            return in_array($permission, $this->permissions['permissions']);
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much i have spent to much time on trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

`array_column` doesn't support 1D arrays, it returns an empty array if so.

Your $permissions array is 1D, so just use `$this->permissions['permission']` to access it.

```
return in_array($permission, $this->permissions['permissions']);
```

Example:

```
$array =  ['permissions' => ['1', '2']];
echo (int)in_array('1', array_column($array, 'permissions')); // 0
echo (int)in_array('1', $array['permissions']); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  this will work.

```
$permission = json_decode('{"permissions":["1","2"]}',true);
echo "<pre>";print_r($permission);
if(is_array($permission)){
 echo "this is an array";
}else{
  echo "Not an array";
}
```

Thanks